# Select and trigger popup on marker via javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible using javascript to trigger a select on an openlayers marker?
I have access to the name and coordinates of the marker, at the moment I am using setcenter to adjust the map to show the marker but I can not find an api call for selecting markers? Hopefully I'm just missing something simple!

Cheers,
Paul

**update**

So the use case is:

- Auto complete search that shows place names
- select a place name
- map scrolls to the correct lat/long

Now I need to trigger the marker popup that is in the centre of the screen.

Note:
I have popups working via mouse clicks.

Answer (score 1):

you can select whether you want a Popup to appear on a MouseOver event or on a MouseClick event, go to Admin - Structures - Openlayers - Maps, edit the map you are using and you can change these on the 'Behaviors' tab. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the description with hopefully a better example of the problem.